# PHP application - Email confirm text, one bit of text displays as strikethrough

Tags: php, html-email

this is an odd happening- We have PHP web form.  Client submits form, data goes to db and a confirmation email is generated and sent to user(s).  Here is the odd thing--  Sporadically, a field, a particular field will display it's text as strike-through.  The field is a drop-down field, so they can't enter special chars themselves.

As I stated, it occurs sporadically, so they can get several email confirms that display the request details correctly, then one will appear that has a strike-through in this on particular field.  It always happens with the BU field and doesn't seem to matter what value is selected.   See attached image example

Their email client is Outlook.  We have several clients that use this app, have never had this happen.

I've Google'd around, but don't see anything.

Do anyone have any suggestions on what I could check to find the culprit.

[image: example of strikethrough email confirmation text]

More INFO
Got the client for forward me the email.  What is happening is their version is Outlook is taking the `<span>` tag and changing it to `<s>` which is strike thru.  This is a auto generating form, so the same code produces the same fields.  I say this because, they have several other dropdown felds on the form and the value displays correctly, without the strike thru and with the  tag in tact.

Comment: You should probably crop the image so people can actually view it. Right now it is 3840px x 1344px of which most of that is white space.

Comment: Is that value stored in a database? Have you looked at the source code of the email in Outlook, is it an html tag or a style/css that is causing it?

Comment: How are you generating the mail, exactly?

Comment: Pitchinnate:  goodness - sorry about that, i have cropped the image

Comment: Pitchinnate:  the value is stored in mysql db.  the source code is html.

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly solve this problem, we need to look at the HTML that is generated when the email contains the strikethrough. There should be a `<S>` or `<Strike>` tag getting inserted into the page.

Then, you need to check each layer of the code that is generating the email to see how that HTML could have been emitted. It would be helpful if you could repeatedly generate the same email with the bad tag - that way should be able to dig through the code and track it down.

Comment: HI Justin - that is the catch right there.  This happens, maybe once a month and they get a couple hundred confirmation emails within a month, so it is really hard to trace.

Comment: Can they forward you an old email with the problem? Do you have a log of the outbound emails? Or alternatively, can you look at the data for one of the bad emails to try and reconstruct how it was generated?